# R namespace access and match.fun

Tags: r, namespaces, package

I'm working on an R package where one of the functions contains a `match.fun` call to a function in a package that's imported to the package namespace. But on loading the package, the `match.fun` call can't find the function name. From [Hadley Wickham's description](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/Namespaces) I think I'm doing everything right, but this is clearly not the case.

Example:

```
# in the package file header, for creation of the NAMESPACE via roxygen2:
##` @import topicmodels

# The function declaration in the package
ModelTopics <- function(doc.term.mat, num.topics, topic.method="LDA"){
  topic.fun <- match.fun(topic.method)
  output <- topic.fun(doc.term.mat, k=num.topics)
  return(output)

}
```

And then in R:

```
> library(mypackage)
> sample.output <- ModelTopics(my.dtm, topic.method="LDA", num.topics=5)
Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : 
  object 'LDA' of mode 'function' was not found
```

From my understanding of namespaces, the `match.fun` call should have access to the package namespace, which should include the `topicmodels` functions. But that doesn't appear to be the case here. If I import `topicmodels` directly to the global namespace for the R session, then this works.

Any help is much appreciated. This is R64 2.14.1 running on OSX.

UPDATE:
The package is [here](https://github.com/markhuberty/leghist)

Re the DESCRIPTION file, perhaps that's the problem: roxygen2 doesn't update the DESCRIPTION file with `Imports:` statements. But none of the other packages are listed there, either; only the `match.fun` calls appear to be affected.

Re the NAMESPACE extract, here's the import section:

```
import(catspec)
import(foreach)
import(gdata)
import(Hmisc)
import(igraph)
import(lsa)
import(Matrix)
import(plyr)
import(RecordLinkage)
import(reshape)
import(RWeka)
import(stringr)
import(tm)
import(topicmodels)
```

Comment: +1 Nice question. Is your package on github or somewhere we can see the code?

Comment: Can you please also add 1) the extract from the NAMESPACE file that shows that `topicmodels` gets imported, and 2) the extract from DESCRIPTION that shows `Imports: topicmodels`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe this an issue of scope. Although you have imported `topicmodels` and thus `LDA`, you haven't exported these functions, so they aren't available in the search path.

From `?match.fun`:

> *`match.fun` is not intended to be used at the top level since it will
>   perform matching in the parent of the caller.*

Thus, since you are using `ModelTopics` in the global environment, and `LDA` isn't available in the global environment, the `match.fun` call fails.

---

It seems to me you have two options:

### Option 1: use `get`

An alternative would be to use `get` where you can specify the environment.  Consider this: try to use `match.fun` to find `print.ggplot` in the package `ggplot2`:

```
match.fun("print.ggplot")
Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : 
  object 'print.ggplot' of mode 'function' was not found
```

Since `print.ggplot` isn't exported, `match.fun` can't find it.

However, `get` does find it:

```
get("print.ggplot", envir=environment(ggplot))
function (x, newpage = is.null(vp), vp = NULL, ...) 
{
    set_last_plot(x)
    if (newpage) 
        grid.newpage()
    data <- ggplot_build(x)
    gtable <- ggplot_gtable(data)
    if (is.null(vp)) {
        grid.draw(gtable)
    }
    else {
        if (is.character(vp)) 
            seekViewport(vp)
        else pushViewport(vp)
        grid.draw(gtable)
        upViewport()
    }
    invisible(data)
}
<environment: namespace:ggplot2>
```

### Option 2: Export the functions from `topicmodels` that you need

If you make the necessary functions from `topicmodels` available in your NAMESPACE, your code should also work.

Do this by either:

- Selective exporting `LDA` and other functions to the namespace using `@export`
- Declare a dependency, using `Depends: topicmodels` - this is the same as calling `library(topicmodels)` in the global environment. This will work, but is possibly a bit of a brute force approach. It also means that any subsequent `library` call can mask your `LDA` function, thus leading to unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question: the DESCRIPTION file wasn't updating the `Imports:` and `Depends:` fields after re-roxygenizing the updated code. Hence the `match.fun` issues. Out of curiousity, why does this affect `match.fun` but not a range of other function calls made elsewhere to imported package functions?

Comment: Are you using `Imports:topicmodels` or `Depends:topicmodels`?

Comment: I'm using `Depends:topicmodels`